# How do i wait for a specific frame to load? I'm using selenium webdriver 2.24

Tags: webdriver, frames

I used the webdriver backed selenium to wait for a specific frame to load. since in certain cases the switching to a specific frame fails because the frame hasn't loaded.
The code I use is

```
selenium.waitForFrameToLoad(frameJCLeft, strTimeOut);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(frameJCLeft);
```

Please let me know if there's a method as I'm planning to eliminate selenium backed webdriver and only use the webdriver api

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use Web Driver Wait and Expected Condition class to achieve this.

Try this code.

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameName);
```

The above code will wait for a `given frame up to 10 seconds`. If the frame is available then it switches to the given frame. Otherwise, it throws a `TimeoutException`.

The time limit depends upon the application and user wish.

For more info  http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(java.lang.String)

Comment: Is there anyway I can introduce a 'or' statement here assuming I have two different names for the same frame in two environments?

Comment: 404 on the link

Answer (score -1):

I would switch to using Selenium 2, and use RemoteWebDriver instead of "WebDriver backed selenium 1.0 stuff".   Then, I would play around with [WebDriver.TargetLocator](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html) .

Comment: As i mentioned "I'm planning to eliminate selenium backed webdriver and only use the webdriver api" exactly what I'm doing but i cudnt find the correct expected wait condition, anyways thanks for the reply mate.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own onFrameLoad() method that blocks and waits for the page title or some other expected object to appear in the frame?  With something like that, you can re-use it when you switch to a local RemoteWebDriver .

Comment: The Webdriver.TargetLocator link is no longer valid