# Selenium WebDriver: How to wait for iframes to load completely? Can click on iframe element text box id = “div_4_1_2_1_1-lnk”

Tags: testing, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Question : I'm testing a page with an iframe whose contents are generated dynamically by JavaScript. I've to wait for the iframe to be loaded completely to make sure that all elements I need are present.

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" style="border: 0px none; width: 100%; height: 290px; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; overflow: auto;" dojoattachpoint="frame" title="Fill Quote" src=" =1&zTaskId=9309&zResetContext=true&coachDebugTrace=none>
   ------------------------------------------------
  <input id="div_4_1_1_1_1_1_2-in" class="p-field span12" type="text">
```

I have tried below code ,

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 4000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("div_4_1_2_1_1-lnk"))));
```

But it's not working. And this iframe has dynamically generated only his title

Output :

```
Nov 22, 2013 2:52:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.id: div_4_1_2_1_1-lnk)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the      remote browser. It may have died.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium has one expected condition to solve your problem  :

```
ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(locator)
```

I recommend you read this [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515120/how-do-i-wait-for-a-specific-frame-to-load-im-using-selenium-webdriver-2-24)