# Selenium don't show the text of cells

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I'm using Selenium to automate a test. I need to read the values of some cells. With my code, I can collect the correct number of cells, and it seems to be the correct cells, but in the field text, it doesn't show any value. I used this same code in other tables and it worked perfectly.

I'm filtering for the class name, I tried to collect other cells and it didn't show text either.

The code of a cell looks like this:
`<td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right"> 3.131,69</td>`

And my sentence of Selenium code:

`ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> celdasF = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class=\"RS_Celda_Contrato\"]"));`

In other cases where I have used this technique. I have loaded the elements in the collection, just as it does now, but the text field has the value of the cell. I want to insist that the correct number of rows is loaded in the collection, then it is not a problem of visibility of the frame, nor is it that the table is not the correct one.

[EDIT]
The code of the html table:

```
    <frame name="hiddenFrame" src="/Operaciones/blanc.htm" scrolling="no" target="hidden" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize="">
    <frame name="area" src="BasePage.aspx?a=1010" noresize="" scrolling="auto" target="area" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <html>
    <head id="Head1">[...]</head>
<body id="_body">
    [...]
<table class="RS_Tabla" id="Tabla_Resumen_Saldos" xmlns="urn:Fibanc:Esquemas.xsd" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0"><colgroup><col width="25px"><col width="545px"><col width="115px"><col width="115px"></colgroup><tbody><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Cabecera"><span style="text-transform:uppercase">Resumen de Posiciones</span>
          &nbsp;
          <input id="_Checkbox Predeterminada" type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('',this.checked)" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Vista predeterminada</span><script type="text/javascript">

            $(".hoverMenu").hover(function(){
            $(this).css({"background": "url(/images/priv_tabs_fondo_on.gif) repeat-x", "color": "white", "cursor": "hand"});
            }, function(){
            $(this).css({"background-image": "none", "background-color": "#DDEDF9", "color": "black", "cursor": "default"});
            }
            );

            function pulsaBoton1(){
            $("#_MyWorld").click();
            __doPostBack('', 'MyWorld2');
            }

            function pulsaBoton2(){
            $("#_MyWorld2").click();
            __doPostBack('', 'MyWorld');
            }
          </script><style type="text/css">
            .flecha-up {
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
            border-left: 10px solid transparent;
            border-right: 10px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 7px solid #DDEDF9;
            font-size: 0px;
            line-height: 0px;
            margin-left: 35%;
            margin-top: 4px;
            position: absolute;
          </style><span style="font-weight:normal;" hidden="true">Vista predeterminada</span></td><td class="RS_Celda_Cabecera" align="center">Saldo (€)</td><td class="RS_Celda_Cabecera_Fin" align="center">Disponible (€)</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Grupo">Cuentas a la Vista</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo" align="right">
          &nbsp;3.657.933,91</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
              3.651.397,25</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2102', 'lci=10010506191378')">Cuenta Corriente ES30.0186.1001.91.0506191378</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        3.131,69</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        3.131,69</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2102', 'lci=50010509275930')">Cuenta Corriente ES88.0186.5001.67.0509275930</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        1.942.482,31</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        1.942.482,31</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2102', 'lci=10014500000120002')">Cuenta Divisa USD ES11.0186.1001.96.4500000120</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        1.712.319,91</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        1.705.783,25</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Grupo">Fondos de Inversión</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo" align="right">
          &nbsp;1.980.879,12</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
              1.980.879,12</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2401', 'lci=2250000013')">Fibanc Pensiones 22/50000013</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        2.182,47</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        2.182,47</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2304', 'lci=102550619137')">Mediolanum Mercados Emergentes L 1025/50619137</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        695.164,31</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        695.164,31</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2304', 'lci=105250619137')">Mediolanum Europa R.V. L 1052/50619137</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        1.283.532,34</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        1.283.532,34</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Grupo">Planes de Pensiones</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo" align="right">
          &nbsp;19.302,82</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
              19.302,82</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2405', 'lci=121760050048')">Europension Plan 1217/60050048</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        19.302,82</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        19.302,82</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Grupo">Valores Depositados</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo" align="right">
          &nbsp;0,00</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
              0,00</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2323', 'lci=118600661161')">Depósito de Valores 1186/00661161</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        0,00</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        0,00</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Grupo">Otros Activos</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo" align="right">
          &nbsp;154.149,91</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
              154.149,91</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2302', 'lci=121300338791')">All Funds 1213/00338791</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        154.149,91</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        154.149,91</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Grupo">Challenge</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo" align="right">
          &nbsp;217.120,93</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
              217.120,93</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2304', 'lci=121201116638')">Challenge 1212/01116638</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        217.120,93</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        217.120,93</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Grupo">Best Brands</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo" align="right">
          &nbsp;4.620.989,90</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
              4.620.989,90</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2304', 'lci=121200942557')">Best Brands 1212/00942557</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        2.878.381,79</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        2.878.381,79</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2304', 'lci=121201227336')">Best Brands 1212/01227336</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        832.630,40</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        832.630,40</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2304', 'lci=121201614619')">Best Brands 1212/01614619</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        909.977,71</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        909.977,71</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Grupo">Index Linked Mediolanum International Life</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo" align="right">
          &nbsp;499.980,00</td><td class="RS_Celda_Grupo_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
              475.862,97</td></tr><tr><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato">&nbsp;</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" style="border-left:none;"><a class="rs" href="javascript:doAction('2348', 'lci=121502025763')">DP Coupon Express Dual Barrier XXI 1215/02025763</a></td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        499.980,00</td><td class="RS_Celda_Contrato_Fin" align="right">
        &nbsp;
        475.862,97</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="RS_Celda_Cabecera" align="right">
          &nbsp;Total a su Favor</td><td class="RS_Celda_Cabecera" align="right">
          &nbsp;11.150.356,59</td><td class="RS_Celda_Cabecera_Fin" align="right">
          &nbsp;
          11.119.702,90</td></tr></tbody></table>
[...]
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The full code of the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TheFotografiaClienteTest()
{
    TheLogInTest();

    //Accesing the appropriate menu
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("gestion_de_clientes_A")).Click();

    //The operation is executed in a new window
    string current = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
    PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
    string newHandle = finder.Click(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"90002147\"]")));
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(newHandle);
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("frame[name='area']")));

    //Accesing a client
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"Template_FormControl_ccSelectorTitular_txtCliente\"]")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Template_FormControl_ccSelectorTitular_txtCliente")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Template_FormControl_ccSelectorTitular_txtCliente")).SendKeys("199655");

    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Template_FormControl_ccSelectorTitular_imgBuscarTitular")).Click();

    //Waiting for the table to load
    WaitUntilElementVisible(By.Id("Tabla_Resumen_Saldos"));

    //Saving values for later comparation
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> celdas = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class=\"RS_Celda_Contrato\"]"));

    //Storing the values in string format
    List<string> saldos = new List<string>();

    for(int j=3; j<celdas.Count; j = j + 4)
    {
        saldos.Add(celdas[j].Text.Trim(' '));
    }

    //Returning to the main window
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[0]);

    //Switching to another web to make the comparation of values
    TheLogInFibancTest("12345");

    //accession the appropiate menu
    js.ExecuteScript("doAction('2011', 'prd=1')");

    //Waiting for the table to load
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
    wait.Until(wd => (DateTime.Now - now) - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000) > TimeSpan.Zero);
//Storing the cells values of the table THIS is the table that is readed without the data in the Text propiety       
        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> celdasFibanc = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class=\"RS_Celda_Contrato\"]"));


        List<string> saldosFibanc = new List<string>();

        for (int j = 2; j < celdasFibanc.Count; j = j + 3)
        {
            saldosFibanc.Add(celdasFibanc[j].Text.Trim(' '));
        }

        //checking quatity of values
        if (saldosFibanc.Count == saldos.Count)
        {
            //Comparing results
            for (int i =0; i<saldos.Count; i++)
            {
                if (saldos[i]!=saldosFibanc[i])
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[EDIT 2]
I just realiced in the Object it says that the cells have Displayed = false but that's not true.. I can see it in the web
[image: Capture]

[EDIT 3]
Tried to wait and switch to the frame "area", just before the cells load, but it timedout (OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 10 seconds'):

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, span);
wait2.Until(ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("area"));
```

[EDIT 4]
Also tried to do a read from a single element with the full XPath, but it doesn't charge the value in the text propiety either...

`IWebElement prueba = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]"));`

Comment: So, is table dynamically loaded?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the data of my DB. But I have inserted a delay of 10 seconds (enough time for it to fully load) and still does not load the data.

`var now = DateTime.Now;
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
wait.Until(wd => (DateTime.Now - now) - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000) > TimeSpan.Zero);`

Comment: Post your code inside the question. Also, provide the HTML of the needed table.

Comment: Done, I can't post the entire HTML, but I think this code is the important part of the question. Thanks.

Comment: Seems your elements are inside the `iframe`. You need to switch to it before interaction with elements.

Comment: That's the first thing I checked, because I had the same problem before. I tried to switch to the frame and it gives me an exception: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: frame[name='area']'.

But if the problem were that it would not find the cells, right? And when I execute the load in fact, the number of elements corresponding to the number of cells in the table are generated in the test execution...

Comment: Use explicit wait for switching to the `iframe`.

Comment: Already did that. I used the SwitchTo between the wait block and the ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> instruction....

Is that what you meant?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515120/how-do-i-wait-for-a-specific-frame-to-load-im-using-selenium-webdriver-2-24

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it throws an exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: 'Timed out after 10 seconds'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've an answer. My problem was that I switched to a frame and then I was trying to switch to another frame that is on the same level. I needed to return to the default frame and then switch to the other frame

```
  //If there's a popup we close it
            if (IsElementPresent(By.Id("contentPop")))
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("contentPop")));

                if (IsElementPresent(By.Id("ImageButton1")))
                {
                    driver.FindElement(By.Id("ImageButton1")).Click();
                    confirmarSegundoCodigoHTML();
                }


                if (IsElementPresent(By.Id("btnCerrar")) && driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnCerrar")).Displayed)
                    driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnCerrar")).Click();

                driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
                driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("frame[name='area']")));
            }
```